# How can I reuse a variable in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, variables, types

I want to use my variable `children` for different cases:

```
var children = [];

if (folderPath == '/') {
      var children = rootFolder;
} else {
      var children = folder.childs;
}
```

But I get the error message:

> variable 'children' must be of type 'any[]' but here has type
> 'Folder[]'

What does this mean?

Comment: `var children:any = []` do this and its works.

Comment: @BrijeshKalkani No, **never** do that. Then you're losing all benefits you get from TypeScript.

Comment: `var children: string | number | Date | Blob` so use this.

Comment: @BrijeshKalkani That will also not work. Why would you think there are Blobs involved in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if "using a variable for different cases" involves using them for different types, then you're Doing Something Wrong.

Assuming `rootFolder` is of type `Folder`, and `folder.childs` is `Folder[]`, your code looks like it could be something like

```
const children: Folder[] = (folderPath === '/' ? [rootFolder] : folder.childs);
```

and in fact you should be able to just do

```
const children = (folderPath === '/' ? [rootFolder] : folder.childs);
```

too and let inference handle things.

If you want to use `if`, then

```
let children: Folder[];

if (folderPath === '/') {
   children = [rootFolder];
} else {
   children = folder.childs;
}
```

should be fine; TypeScript will notice the variable is always definitely set after that `if`, even if it has no initial value.